# Dereferencing an array in Perl

Tags: perl

Consider:

```
sub binary_search {
   my ($array, $word) = @_;
   my ($low, $high) = (0, @$array -1);
}
```

I am going through a book and the explanation for `@$array` the book provides is that it is dereferencing the scalar variable `$array` to get the array underneath.

I am a bit confused on this statement. I understand that $ is a scalar variable and @ is an array variable in Perl.

1. Why isn't it `my (@array, $word) = @_;`?
2. How is there an array in $array (isn't `$` a scalar?) which can be reached by `@$array`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function expects a *reference* to an array, not an array, as the first argument. See [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) for info on array references. If you tried to evaluate:

```
my (@array, $word) = @_;
```

the `@array` would gobble up all the input and `$word` would be left undefined.

The method could have been written to expect a word and then an array, in which case you could do:

```
my ($word, @array) = @_;
```

but that's not what you have.

Note that when you call a function with an array in the actual argument list, what Perl does is interpolate the elements of the array as if they were individual arguments to the function. It does not pass the array as a single object. See the [perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html) documentation for details.

Comment: whats the advantage of sending in a reference over the actual array?

Comment: @ealeon - Perl flattens all arrays in an actual parameter list. That is, if you call `foo(@someArray, @someOtherArray);`, then `foo` receives as actual arguments all the elements of `@someArray` and `@someOtherArray` as a single argument list.

Comment: You can't send an actual array. Functions only accept list of scalars as arguments.

Comment: @ikegami - Well, yes and no. It depends on what you mean by "send". You can, in fact, use an array in a function call. From the docs: _"all functions are passed as parameters one single flat list of scalars, and all functions likewise return to their caller one single flat list of scalars. Any arrays or hashes in these call and return lists will collapse, losing their identities..."_. So, for example, you can call `foo(@stuff)` and if `foo` is defined as `sub foo() { my @stuff = @_; ...}` it will, in fact, "receive" the array (although "recover" might be a better word).

Comment: @Ted Hopp, Send: "To move from point A (the caller) to point B (the called sub)", or "To pass as an argument". You can send the *elements* of an array, or a *reference* to one, but you can't send an *array*. Functions only accept list of scalars as arguments. And no, `my @stuff = @_;` doesn't receive or recover it at all. Try adding elements to `@stuff`. Try changing the value of its elements. Any magic the original had is no longer present. etc etc etc. Why do you contradict me then post a quote that repeats what I said almost word for word?

Comment: So you can discuss the merits of passing the elements of an array to a sub (`f(@a)`: ease of chaining functions calls) and the merits of passing a reference (`f(\@a)`: efficiency, only way to provide an array to a sub via arguments), but "the advantage of sending in a reference over the actual array" is that only the former is possible.

Comment: @ikegami - I was just trying to draw a distinction between passing an array intact to a function (which you are right to point out cannot be done, and which I think I addressed in my post to start with) with what someone might wrongly perceive you to be saying: that an array cannot be used in a function call. I certainly wasn't trying to suggest that an array can be passed intact. However, I think that perhaps my example just added to the confusion.

Comment: I was replying to a comment made after your post, not your post. Let's not start pretending that `f(g())` passes a function to `f` or that `f(@array)` passes an array to `f`.